# PHPでstripslashes関数を使うとIPNのValidationがうまくいかない

Tags: php, paypal

PayPalのウェブペイメントプラスでクレジット決済を行った後、IPNデータを取得してシステムへのデータ取り込みをPHPで書いているのですが、送られてきたデータが正しいかPayPalに問い合わせるValidationが、VERIFIEDでなくINVALIDで返ってきてしまいます。

Answer (score 0):

原因は、SHIFT JISの0x5C問題、いわゆる「ダメ文字」というやつで、今回だと「圭」が対象でした。

PayPalのIPNでは送られてきたでデータをそのままの順序、そのままの内容でPayPalに送り返すことで
通知が正しいもの＝VERIFIEDだと認識されますが、その送り返すデータを作成するときに
`stripslashes` 関数をつかっていたため、ダメ文字の0x5Cが削除されてしまうために、
受信文字列と送信文字列が一致しない結果INVALIDが返却されていました。

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= ""&$key=$value"";
}
```

php.iniでmagic_quotesがOFFになっているので、そもそも `stripslashes()` は呼び出す必要はなかったですね。

IPNの実装方法についてはこちらに詳しく載っています。
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/

---

*この投稿は [@kimaihack66 さん自身の投稿 (質問)](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/10509) に含まれていた内容を元に、個別の回答として抜き出して コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*